# What is the difference between X-inches diagonal, X-inches viewable, and the modern X-inch "class" in monitors and tv's?

Tags: display, lcd, tv, crt

I'm really dumbstruck by this one. I see it everywhere now, though. The last time I bought a monitor, a Samsung 1941BW, it was just marketed as *19-inches widescreen*. Before that, LCDs, TVs, and CRTs were advertising "viewable" or "diagonal" area, and would often come with a sticker or logo which described the diagonal line, and where I should measure if I wanted to check for myself.

But, how the heck do I know what a *22-inch class* monitor is? I just bought a TV which is marked *19-inch "class"*. What is this? It's even on laptop ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Diagonal**: the actual diagonal corner-to-corner size of the display, measured (more or less) exactly. *e.g. 13.3"*
- **Class**: The diagonal measurement rounded to a whole number for easier discussion and marketing. *e.g. 13"*
- **Viewable**: Not generally used anymore. If you do see it these days you're either looking at a CRT monitor or it's being used synonymously with the diagonal measurement.

Comment: To be clear: Is it correct that most advertised "diagonal" measurements these days equate to "viewable"? Or are they also including the screen bezel and other areas where content is not displayed?

Comment: I know it's late, but, @Iszi, yes, it means viewable.  It's the dimension of the actual display area, not the bezel.

I do wish bezel width were given, but nobody does that, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

"Class" is them rounding the decimal off of the actual number. 21.7 vs 22.3, both "22 inch class". You kind of get it in laptops these days where a 15" laptop can be anything from 14.9" to 15.6".

'Viewable' went by the way-side when CRTs went away.